# Fisher information reparametrization formula in non-bijective cases

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, information-theory, fisher-information, information-geometry

The formula writes as this:
$$I(X) = \left(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial X}\right)^\top I(Z) \left(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial X}\right),$$
in particular, if $Z = AX$, we have
$$I(X) = A^\top I(Z) A.$$
Based on my understanding if $A$ is a short-fat matrix, this still holds. My question is that what if $AX$ is not sufficient in parametrizing the distribution. For example, let's fix the covariance matrix, multivariate Gaussian can be parametrize by its mean $\mu$. However, $A\mu$ is not sufficient in parametrizing the distribution if $A$ is a short fat matrix. In that case, do we still have the formula? The formula relies on the fact that
$$A^\top \nabla_{z} p(y|z) = \nabla_{x} p(y|x).$$
However, $p(y|z)$ doesn't even exist in the aforementioned Gaussian case.

Comment: Could you make more precise what is meant by a short fat matrix?

Comment: Yes, number of rows of $A$ is less than the number of columns of $A$, assuming $A$ has full row rank.